# React decide order or rendering

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a page(component) that is very big in size, for example:

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="content0"></div>
    <div className="content1"></div>
    <div className="content2"></div>
    <div className="main"></div>
    <div className="content3"></div>
    <div className="content4"></div>
    <div className="content5"></div>
</div>
```

As far as I understand, `React.lazy` helps webpack with bundling and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to decide ordering of render so that when `<div className="main">` loaded and rendered, then other components start loading and rendering?

Comment: Could you provide a link to `React.lazy` or expand a bit on it so we can see what you're referring to?

Comment: here's the link https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: As far as I know, lazy loading refers to loading important content first then load rest of the content. However, `React.lazy` seems to refer to spliting and loading webpack bundle. Is conditional rendering only way to achieve this?